# Relationship returning nothing when trying to reference

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I am currently trying to reference all the guilds the user belongs to, but right now, it doesn't seem to be working as intended. When I try to use `$user->guilds(),` it shows that it has a relation but doesn't return anything. So I thought I might need to do a pivot table.

**User Migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('descrim');
    $table->bigInteger('snowflake')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
    $table->string('banner')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('mfa_enabled')->default(false);
    $table->boolean('verified')->default(false);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Guild Migration**

```
Schema::create('guilds', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('id');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('user_snowflake')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('icon');
    $table->string('owner_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('permissions');
    $table->string('permissions_new');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

**User Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Guild;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function guilds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Guild::class);
    }
}
```

**Guild Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Guild extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `$user->guilds`, without the `()`. The `()` returns the method, which you can chain. `$user->guilds` is essentially shorthand for `$user->guilds()->get()` (they should return the same thing in most cases)

Comment: @TimLewis Well I a feel like an idiot. Thank you, I really do need to take more break often...

Comment: No worries, and you're not an idiot   Anyone who has worked with Laravel's relationships has invariably run into this issue at some point, myself included. Once you know what to look out for, you're all set, but it's a very common misconception.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `()`, instead of `$user->guilds()` do `$user->guilds`.